# Why Databricks Delta is copying unmodified rows even when merge doesn't update anything?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks, delta-lake

When I run a following query:

```
merge into test_records t
using (
select id, "senior developer" title, country from test_records where country = 'Brazil'
) u
on t.id = u.id
when matched and (t.id <> u.id) then -- this is just to be sure that nothing will get updated
  update set t.title = u.title, t.updated_at = now()
when not matched then 
  insert (id, title, country, created_at, updated_at) values (id, title, country, now(), now());
```

I still see the following data when I run describe history of the target table:

```
{"numTargetRowsCopied": "2", "numTargetRowsDeleted": "0", "numTargetFilesAdded": "1", "numTargetRowsInserted": "0", "numTargetRowsUpdated": "0", "numOutputRows": "2", "numSourceRows": "2", "numTargetFilesRemoved": "1"}
```

And in the spark ui i see this:

[image]

So the unmodified rows are being rewritten without any (?) reason. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER:** I've been looking into it and I can only give you how the code looks, but not why it does so.

---

This no-match-row MERGE INTO is resolved to [MergeIntoCommand](https://github.com/delta-io/delta/blob/a05c97e54a50118de3b2f8afdbed33887edb45c2/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/commands/MergeIntoCommand.scala#L94) logical command (that is executed on the driver). You can find all the performance metrics [here](https://github.com/delta-io/delta/blob/a05c97e54a50118de3b2f8afdbed33887edb45c2/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/commands/MergeIntoCommand.scala#L122-L131) (with [numTargetRowsCopied](https://github.com/delta-io/delta/blob/a05c97e54a50118de3b2f8afdbed33887edb45c2/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/commands/MergeIntoCommand.scala#L124)).

That leads us to [writeAllChanges](https://github.com/delta-io/delta/blob/a05c97e54a50118de3b2f8afdbed33887edb45c2/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/commands/MergeIntoCommand.scala#L316-L320) with our metric

What's interesting about this code is that it chooses the join type to be `rightOuter` or `fullOuter`. Turn `DEBUG` logging level on for `org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.MergeIntoCommand` logger to see the internal messages printed out to the logs.

Another very interesting thing is that the metrics are calculated as UDFs (!) Ours is [here](https://github.com/delta-io/delta/blob/a05c97e54a50118de3b2f8afdbed33887edb45c2/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/commands/MergeIntoCommand.scala#L344).

In the end, [these lines](https://github.com/delta-io/delta/blob/a05c97e54a50118de3b2f8afdbed33887edb45c2/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/commands/MergeIntoCommand.scala#L536-L538) are where the UDF gets executed and the metric incremented. The comment is of particular interest:

```
// Target row did not match any source row, so just copy it to the output
```

I think that says it all. No match leads to incrementing `numTargetRowsCopied` metric. I'm guessing that you've got two rows in the target table, don't you?